# Images Cutoff/ Disappear on Tablet View

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on making my site responsive. Right now the text is responsive, but my images are getting partially cutoff on tablet view, and disappear behind my text description boxes on mobile. Any help would be great. Below is my code and how my site looks at tablet view. [image: looks at tablet view.]

```css
CSS

.work {
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    padding: 4vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.UMMA {
    background-image: url(../img/UMMA.jpg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
.UMMA {
        background-position-x: 30%;
    }
}
```

```html
<li class="section UMMA”>
    <div class="description">
        <h2>UMMA</h2>
        <p>Making the on-site museum experience more engaging for visitors.</p>
        <a class="button" target="_blank" href=“UMMA.html”>View Project</a>

    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: try with `z-index`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `background-size:100%;`

```css
.work {
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    padding: 4vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.UMMA {
    background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_fjords.jpg);/*Image use for example*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
.UMMA {
        background-position-x: 30%;
    }
}
```

```html
<li class="section UMMA">
    <div class="description">
      <h2>UMMA</h2>
      <p>Making the on-site museum experience more engaging for visitors.</p>
      <a class="button" target="_blank" href=“UMMA.html”>View Project</a>

    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried adding the background-size: 100%; and background-repeat: no-repeat;  to my code, but it didn't change anything. Any other ideas?

Comment: sure thing! My site is not live right now but here is a link to my github repo https://github.com/amberkar/Work

Comment: You can add in css `@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) { .UMMA, .plot, .Centro, .peapod, .Lyra { min-height: 450px; }  }`